# where's the elixir dependencies respository?

Tags: elixir

In an elixir project `mix.exs` file, we include the dependencies like so

```
 defp deps(_) do
   [
     {:phoenix, "~> 0.6.1"},
     {:ecto, "~> 0.2.0"}
   ]
 end
```

Where's the repository that stores the elixir code for these dependencies?

Coming from a Ruby background, the deps function is analagous to a Gemfile.  But I know gems by default pull from "rubygems.org".  In otherwords, what's like the Rubygems.org for elixir?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html#external-dependencies), it's in the [Hex Package Manager](https://hex.pm).

Comment: It's also worth noting that dependencies can also be pulled directly from GitHub repos as well.